# Admin dashboard with Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, npm-install

[start angular - sb admin angular](https://github.com/start-angular/sb-admin-angular)

I am trying to set up admin dashboard in windows. However, i have stuck with some issues when installing using

> npm install

The error is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7pN4.png)

I am now confused with all. I am trying to do in xampp. Do we need a xampp to do all? I am a bit confused. Anybody tried this before, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is the instructions in the read.me for [sb admin angular](https://github.com/start-angular/sb-admin-angular)

ignore the `npm start` short cut that the doc tells you to do, this is what is preventing grunt from starting the server.

If you type `grunt serve` into the terminal the server will start.

Comment: And you have the latest version of node?

Comment: Yes. We have latest one.

Comment: The `npm start` short cut doesn't work use `grunt serve` and it run for you. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Let me know if this answer worked for you, and feel free to accept the answer as well if it did.